# Teaching as the pinnacle of career

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find a short story I remember reading probably in the sixties, about a reverse career path where the ultimate goal and privilege is to be a classroom teacher.

Comment: Why are people voting this as too broad? It's instantly recognisable.

Comment: We've had this question before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Gladly Wolde He Lerne](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Gladly_Wolde_He_Lerne) by Harry Turtledove.

> *Once his exams were over, Collins had cut way back on his caffeine intake. Even so, he hardly slept the night before his first day on the new job. “Am I really good enough?” he asked his wife as he picked at breakfast that morning.
>   “You bet you are,” she said. “Now, go get ’em.”
>
>   For all her encouragement, he needed a deep breath to still the fear inside him as he walked up to the enameled door with the tarnished brass 7 on it. He opened the door. He went inside.
>
>   “Good morning, class,” he said, forcing his voice to steadiness.
>
>   “Good morning, teacher,” the children chorused.
>
>   **Teacher. He felt ready to burst with pride. After so long, after so much hard work, at last he’d reached the pinnacle of his profession.***